# Allow fullscreen in innerhtml/iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I am trying to allow user to be able to view a video in fullscreen mode. The video is embed in streamvideo.php inside stream.php using an iframe.

I found that iframe does not allow content to be fullscreen unless we called **allowfullscreen**

When user login into my site. **index.php** using inner html it load **Stream.php** and various iframe is load inside stream.php

Index.php

```
  <li id="onlineslides"><a href="#onlineslides" onclick="load_home2();">OnlineSlides</a></li>


       function load_home2(){
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:auto" type="text/html" data="stream/stream.php" ></object>';
                }
```

Stream.php

```
<iframe src="video/streamvideo.php" id="streamvideoiFrame" frameborder="0" width="800" height="1000" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen=""> ></iframe>
```

when I access **stream.php** directly I am able to view the video in fullscreen. However when I access the link using index.php I am not able to load the video in full screen. How can I solve this?

Comment: does anyone have any suggestion?